# In Python, what's a neat way to recursively wrap text to a set number of characters?

Tags: python, word-wrap

I have this string:

```
text = "abc def ghi jkl mno pqr stu vwx yz\nabc def ghi jkl mno pqr stu vwx yz"
```

I wanna wrap it to a character width (e.g. 5) such that it becomes this:

```
abc d
ef gh
i jkl
 mno 
pqr s
tu vw
x yz
abc d
ef gh
i jkl
 mno 
pqr s
tu vw
x yz
```

Non-recursively, here's what I've got:

```
text_in  = text.split("\n")
text_out = []

width = 5
for line in text_in:
    if len(line) < width:
        text_out.append(line)
    else:
        text_out.append(line[:width])
        text_out.append(line[width:])

print("\n".join(text_out))
```

So, it gets things right only to leading order level:

```
abc d
ef ghi jkl mno pqr stu vwx yz
abc d
ef ghi jkl mno pqr stu vwx yz
```

How should this wrapping be done recursively or in some other neat way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Regex* solution:

```
import re

def wrap_text(text, width):
    if not width:
        return text
    else:
        return re.sub(r'(.{' + str(width) + '})', '\\1\n', text)

text = "abc def ghi jkl mno pqr stu vwx yz\nabc def ghi jkl mno pqr stu vwx yz"
```

---

- `(.{<width>})` - capture each `<width>` number of characters into the 1st parenthesized group `(...)`

Test case #1:

```
print(wrap_text(text, 5))
```

The output:

```
abc d
ef gh
i jkl
 mno 
pqr s
tu vw
x yz
abc d
ef gh
i jkl
 mno 
pqr s
tu vw
x yz
```

---

Test case #2:

```
print(wrap_text(text, 10))
```

The output:

```
abc def gh
i jkl mno 
pqr stu vw
x yz
abc def gh
i jkl mno 
pqr stu vw
x yz
```

Comment: Isn't regular expressions a bit overkill?

Answer (score 1):

i would do this with list comprehension:

```
text = "abc def ghi jkl mno pqr stu vwx yz\nabc def ghi jkl mno pqr stu vwx yz"

res = [text[pos:pos+5] for pos in range(0, len(text), 5)]

for i in res:
    print(i)
```

---

to handle the new line character you can replace the new line with a additional whitespace:

```
text = text.replace("\n", " ")
```

or after list comprehension:

```
for i in res:
    if '\n' in i:
       i = i.strip('\n')
       print(i)
    else:
       print(i)
```

result is now:

```
abc d
ef gh
i jkl
 mno 
pqr s
tu vw
x yz
abc d
ef gh
i jkl
 mno 
pqr s
tu vw
x yz
```

Comment: Aw this is cool, thanks. One thing tho: do you know how to respect the existing  newlines? Like, if it encounters a newline, it should start a new line.

Comment: I have edited it now, hope i understood you in a proper way

Answer (score 1):

What happened to Daniel Roseman's suggestion to use [`textwrap.wrap`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/textwrap.html#textwrap.wrap)? Just for completion, because it disappeared:

```
import textwrap

a = "abc def ghi jkl mno pqr stu vwx yz\nabc def ghi jkl mno pqr stu vwx yz"

for item in textwrap.wrap(a, 5):
    print(item)
```

Answer (score -1):

One can use `for` loop to get substrings:

```
text = "abc def ghi jkl mno pqr stu vwx yz\nabc def ghi jkl mno pqr stu vwx yz"
llen = len(text);     lst = [];     stemp = ""
for i in range(llen):
    if i % 5 == 0 and i>0:
        lst.append(stemp)
        stemp = ""
        stemp += text[i]
    else: 
        stemp += text[i]

for ll in lst: 
    print(ll)
```

Output:

```
abc d
ef gh
i jkl
 mno 
pqr s
tu vw
x yz

abc d
ef gh
i jkl
 mno 
pqr s
tu vw
```

Comment: It will be useful if the negative voter could give his/her reason here in comments.